# What's the wizard prestige class that creates its own familiar?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, prestige-class, content-identification

I'm trying to locate a prestige class.

- The prestige class is designed for wizards.
- One of the requirements is the feat Craft Wondrous Item.
- The class description mentions that the wizard studies and creates life.
- The class enables the wizard to create a familiar rather than summon one.
- It might give the wizard access to healing spells.
- The capstone ability is that the wizard can make a golem.
- I remember the illustration showing a wizard over a cauldron.

What's the name of this prestige class and where can I find it?

Comment: Was the familiar a homunculus, by any chance?

Comment: The sources for pathfinder and 3.5 can vary extensively. Can you recall which of the two this PrC came from?

Comment: A google search of `site:www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes golem` turns up nothing, and the same with familiar instead of golem turns up only some classes that grant particular improved familiars (or are just using the word in terms of familiarity), so that suggests that it’s a 3.5 class.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe you mean *Effigy Master* from Complete Arcane?

It is an arcane caster PrC **(1)** with wondrous item as requirement **(2)** where the character is as said *"Fascinated by the animating force of life itself"* **(3)**, gains the class skill "Craft effigy" that allows it to create constructs **(4)** though there is no healing or cauldron involved.

The art for the effigy master is:

[image: Effigy Master by Franz Vohwinkel]

Answer (score 5):

The fleshwarper from *Lords of Madness* uses grafting to modify and improve his familiar, though it becomes an aberration, not a golem. There’s also no cauldron in the art, though there are a lot of glasses and beakers. Probably not what you had in mind, but just to toss it out there.

The art is

[image: Fleshwarper by Wayne Reynolds]

Note the upgraded monkey familiar.